# Computer won't post / Beep unless Unplugged for a few hours

Tags: power-supply, cables, computers, troubleshooting, motherboard

I'm experiencing this issue for almost a year now. It is slowly getting worse. My motherboard is Gigabyte GA-Z77X-D3H and my PSU is Corsair CX600. The source of the problem most likely has to do with either one of these two components. I have built this PC 6 years ago. Thus this problem started to appear after 5 years. Motherboard is compatible with LGA 1155 chipset only.

As i mentioned, the PC won't beep/boot properly unless unplugged for some time. This time can be 30min, 1 hour, or a few hours (last time -today- it needed 2 hours). I have to unplug all cables from the chassis to bound the causes of the problem. My case (Mid Tower) is a bit cluttered now with all the cables, but i have them all separated and making sure that no cross contacts, or shorts are occuring, so i'm probably ok there.

I have replaced the CMOS battery, the fault isn't there. RAM Sticks, GPU, Storage drives are all working properly. I have also recently installed a custom fan speed controller. Finally all caps on the mobo look fine.

Could someone suggest me some methods i could try to identify which one of the 2 components is failing, or whatever else may be wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention that once the computer is powered on properly then there's no problem at all. I can leave it on for days without an issue.

Comment: This is off topic, because it does not put the issue in the context of engineering-level detail of the circuitry involved.   I will mention though that ages ago I had a desktop PC which would not cleanly do a power-on reset.  For a while I had a pushbutton wired to a reset header on the board, and that worked until replacing it with a faster motherboard freed up by upgrading another machine.   Not sure if modern motherboards have such a jumper, but you could try.  Actual cause is likely either power supply that starts up badly, or a motherboard problem.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the internals from dust? Maybe some component in your PSU has aged or failed and now, with all that clutter and dust, it heats up faster and some thermal protection kicks in even before POST. Have you tried checking the temperature of the PSU case before using the soft switch to power on your PC? Is it mildly warm even before switching it on? Try to clean up your PSU fan and grills from dust, maybe using a vacuum cleaner and/or a can of pressurized air.

Comment: Bad solder joints can be thermally sensitive.

Comment: I can guarantee there is no soldering issues. I have closely inspected the motherboard and the PSU innards. The case is being cleaned regularly approximately 1.5 times per year. It is maintained to the best of my abilities. My suspision is towards any shorts, or contacts that may occur, or simply the electronics of either the PSU or the mobo are ageing and failing.

Comment: There is a MPU on the Mobo that acts as a power ON power OFF sequencer. Also shuts down power supply if a hardware fault is detected or the OS crashes or simply issues a shutdown command. Carefully watch the boot sequence to see when the problem starts.

Comment: The problem will start whenever i try to power on the computer after some time that i shut it off, or even many hours after i shut it off and leave the cables connected and plugged in circuit. What i normally do is shut off the computer at night, remove all cables that provide power to the chassis, press the power switch for ~30secs and then in the morning reconnect and turn it on. My goal is to dissipate all resident electricity in the computer circuits. Only a few of times so far this scheme hasn't worked for me (the frequency of this tends to increase as time passes though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you need to disconnect all internal peripherals (disk, floppy, USB (except keyboard) and test POST functionality for your motherboard.
You can get modern POST cards that will help you (here is an example: [https://www.amazon.com/Desktop-Notebook-Motherboard-Analyzer-Diagnostic/dp/B01HRFQ8YM/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HRFQ8YM))

If you test POST with only your keyboard and display attached you should either get Boot messages on your display, or POST failures on your tester card.

As a quick test I'd ensure your +5 V standby is working correctly, I've seen this impact your ability to turn on a PC with no other side effects once started.

Comment: Ok, i will (again) do a detailed examination of all components and check their voltage levels and report back soon.

Comment: *UPDATE*: I haven't yet pinpointed the source of the problem. However now there's another thing to watch out for. As i said previously if my computer is on, then it can stay on for as long as needed without problems without ever shutting down. That is true. However, now when i run a demanding video game for a while (can even be for 15 minutes) the computer will shut down and then turn on again (not restart - it power-cycles by itself!). Now, i have to find what's the real cause. Is it GPU? Is it PSU? Or is it MOBO? It could be any of them and this is getting hard to troubleshoot. Any ideas?

Comment: *UPDATE*: I bought a PSU tester and found out that the PSU couldn't stabilize its internal circuitry and as such wasn't sending a PG (Power Good) signal on the motherboard (indicator was 0). The PSU had to be left out of power for at least 8-14 hours before the PG signal stabilized again to normal levels (0-100ms). So I bought a new PSU and replaced it. All is working fine for a week now.